# Fechas se guardan en base de datos con hora minutos y segundos

Tags: java, oracle, date

Buenas tengo una aplicación en el que el único cambio que ha sufrido es actualizar el jdk del 6 al 8, y ojdbc del del 6 al 8. Antes de esto las fechas se guardaban sin las horas y minutos y desde este cambio me aparecen con 12:00:00

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por que puede estar ocurriendo esto?, ¿que solución podría hacer para que no se guardaran con las horas sin tener que ir parseando todas la fechas por código?

Comment: Puedes configurar el formato de fecha predeterminado de su aplicación para que no incluya las horas y minutos. Esto se puede hacer utilizando la clase `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` y especificando el formato de fecha deseado.

Comment: Si el campo está definido como tipo date, siempre almacena fecha y tiempo, el tema es cómo lo muestras, ¿cuál es tu select?

Comment: Hola Jesus, sin ver tu código, es imposible saber a que se debe el cambio, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y lo agregues como texto.

Comment: El tema es que antes si consulta el campo con un to_char(fecha, formato) la hora que traía era las 12 de la noche y ahora con el cambio parece que se está guardando las 12 del mediodía. Esto me genera problemas ya que cuando comparo fechas del mismo día no resultan ser las mismas. También tengo alguna consulta con to_char que falla al formatear porque ahora debería indicar la hora en el formato. Formatear se que puedo hacerlo pero tendría que  hacerlo por toda la aplicación y quería saber a qué se debe este cambio y si hay alguna manera de no tener que cambiar todo el código.

Comment: Básicamente la cuestión sería saber el motivo de esto de este cambio al cambiar el ojdbc al 8 ( he vuelto a poner el 6 y todo vuelve a ir bien )para no tener que ir haciendo cambios por todo el programa y que todo funcione igual. El código está basado en spring + hibernate.

Comment: Hola de nuevo, Cuando respondas un comentario, escribe "@nombreDelQueComento", para que este sea notificado. si vamos a jugar a las adivinanzas, casi juraría que el "ojdbc 8", no está configurado con la zona horaria que corresponde (por eso te da 12 hs. de diferencia), si lo configuras bien, debería desaparecer el problema!.